# Why is roc_curve return an additional value for the thresholds (2.0) for some classes?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, probability, roc

I am using python 3.5.2 and sklearn 0.19.1

I have a muticlass problem (3 classes) and I am using `RandomForestClassifier`.
For one of the cass I have
19 unique `predict_proba` values :

```
{0.0,
0.6666666666666666,
0.6736189855024448,
0.6773290780865037,
0.7150826826468751,
0.7175236925236925,
0.7775446850962057,
0.8245648135911781,
0.8631035080004867,
0.8720525244880196,
0.8739595855873906,
0.8787152225755167,
0.9289844333343654,
0.954439314892936,
0.9606503912532541,
0.9771342285323964,
0.9883370916703461,
0.9957401423931763,
1.0}
```

I am computing `roc_curve` and I am expecting the same number of point for the roc curve as I have unique value of probablitity. This is only true for 2 of the 3 classes!

When I looked at the thresholds returned that the `roc_curve` function:

`fpr, tpr, proba = roc_curve(....)`:

I see the same exact value as the one in the list of probability + one new value 2.0 !

```
[2.,
1.,
0.99574014,
0.98833709,
0.97713423,
0.96065039,
0.95443931,
0.92898443,
0.87871522,
0.87395959,
0.87205252,
0.86310351,
0.82456481,
0.77754469,
0.71752369,
0.71508268,
0.67732908,
0.67361899,
0.66666667,
0. ]
```

Why is a new thresholds 2.0 is returned ? I didn't see anything related to that in the documentation.

Any idea ? I am missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`roc_curve` is written so that ROC point corresponding to the highest threshold (`fpr[0]`, `tpr[0]`) is always (0, 0).  If this is not the case, a new threshold is created with an arbitrary value of `max(y_score)+1`.  The relevant code from [the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py#L453):

```
thresholds : array, shape = [n_thresholds]
    Decreasing thresholds on the decision function used to compute
    fpr and tpr. `thresholds[0]` represents no instances being predicted
    and is arbitrarily set to `max(y_score) + 1`.
```

and

```
if tps.size == 0 or fps[0] != 0:
    # Add an extra threshold position if necessary
    tps = np.r_[0, tps]
    fps = np.r_[0, fps]
    thresholds = np.r_[thresholds[0] + 1, thresholds]
```

So it seems in the case you showed you have data given a score of `1.0` that is incorrectly classified.